# i have a code of jw player wont show cc on mobile browsers?

Tags: java, css, jwplayer7

i have this code for jw player it show the cc on desktop browsers but when i open it on my phone it wont show cc button can any one help me

```
<div id="player" class="jwplayer jw-reset jw-state-playing jw-skin-seven jw-stretch-uniform jw-flag-aspect-mode jw-breakpoint-4 jw-flag-user-inactive" tabindex="0" style="width: 100%; height: 270px;">
        <div class="jw-aspect jw-reset" style="padding-top: 56.25%;"></div>
        <div class="jw-media jw-reset"><video class="jw-video jw-reset" src="blob:http://ravitel.com/b8757611-97e2-4dc0-b9af-a76050d03843" __idm_id__="629968897" jw-loaded="data" style="object-fit: fill;"></video></div>

        <div class="jw-preview jw-reset"></div><div class="jw-captions jw-captions-enabled jw-reset" style="height: 363px; font-size: 18.5px;"><div class="jw-captions-window jw-reset"><span class="jw-captions-text jw-reset" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></div></div><div class="jw-title jw-reset" style="display: none; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <div class="jw-title-primary jw-reset"></div>
            <div class="jw-title-secondary jw-reset"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jw-overlays jw-reset"><div id="player_jwpsrv" class="jw-plugin jw-reset"></div><div id="player_related" class="jw-plugin jw-reset jw-plugin-related"></div></div>
        <div class="jw-controls jw-reset"><div class="jw-display-icon-container jw-background-color jw-reset">
        <div class="jw-icon jw-icon-display jw-button-color jw-reset" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Pause"></div>
    </div><div class="jw-controls-right jw-reset"><div class="jw-dock jw-reset">
    </div></div><div class="jw-nextup-container jw-reset"><div class="jw-nextup jw-reset">
        <div class="jw-nextup-tooltip jw-reset">
            <div class="jw-nextup-header jw-reset">

            </div>
            <div class="jw-nextup-body jw-background-color jw-reset">
                <div class="jw-nextup-thumbnail jw-reset"></div>
                <div class="jw-nextup-title jw-reset"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="jw-nextup-close"></button>

    </div><span class="jw-text jw-reset jw-text-alt" role="status"></span></div><div class="jw-group jw-controlbar-right-group jw-reset"><span class="jw-text jw-reset jw-text-duration" role="timer">۰۵:۰۹</span><div class="jw-icon jw-icon-inline jw-button-color jw-reset jw-icon-next" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Next" style="display: none;"></div><div class="jw-icon jw-icon-tooltip jw-icon-hd jw-button-color jw-reset jw-hidden" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Quality" aria-hidden="true"><div class="jw-overlay jw-reset"></div></div><div class="jw-icon jw-icon-tooltip jw-icon-cc jw-reset jw-toggle jw-off" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Closed captions" aria-hidden="true"><div class="jw-overlay jw-reset"></div></div><div class="jw-icon jw-icon-tooltip jw-icon-audio-tracks jw-button-color jw-reset jw-hidden" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Audio tracks" aria-hidden="true"><div class="jw-overlay jw-reset"></div></div><div class="jw-icon jw-icon-inline jw-button-color jw-reset jw-icon-volume" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Volume" style=""></div><div class="jw-icon jw-icon-inline jw-button-color jw-reset jw-icon-cast jw-off" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Chromecast" style="display: none;"></div><div class="jw-slider-volume jw-background-color jw-reset jw-slider-horizontal jw-reset" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="jw-slider-container jw-reset">
            <div class="jw-rail jw-reset"></div>
            <div class="jw-buffer jw-reset"></div>
            <div class="jw-progress jw-reset" style="width: 90%;"></div>
            <div class="jw-knob jw-reset" style="left: 90%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div><div class="jw-icon jw-icon-tooltip jw-icon-volume jw-button-color jw-reset" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Volume" aria-hidden="false"><div class="jw-overlay jw-reset"><div class="jw-slider-volume jw-volume-tip jw-background-color jw-reset jw-slider-vertical jw-reset" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: JWPlayer is from another world. They don't even have their own website in order.